# Licenses PyQt and QT

Tags: gpl, lgpl, license-notice, python

I would like to use PyQT5 and QT5 to create an -internal- application for a friend and his company. I would like to use PyQT GPL license and QT LGPL license.

To respect these licenses, I need to:

- give him the source code when the application is done;
- create a msgBox that defines what QT is, with links to their licenses;
- provide a copy of the GPL license;

Is it correct? Do I forget something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> provide a copy of the GPL license

You not only need to provide a copy of the GNU GPL, but you also need to release the internal application under the GNU GPL.

There is a small chance of [compatibility issues between different versions of the GPL and LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility) that you should consider as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case if you use PySide instead of PyQt.  PySide uses LGPL so your Python code can be whatever license you want.

From [PyQt5 vs PySide2: What's the difference between the two Python Qt libraries?](https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/pyqt5-vs-pyside2/):

> The key difference in the two versions — in fact the entire reason
> PySide2 exists — is licensing. PyQt5 is available under a GPL or
> commercial license, and PySide2 under a LGPL license.
>
> If you are planning to release your software itself under the GPL, or
> you are developing software which will not be distributed, the GPL
> requirement of PyQt5 is unlikely to be an issue. However, if you plan
> to distribute your software without distributing the source you will
> either need to purchase a commercial license from Riverbank for PyQt5
> or use PySide2.
>
> The LGPL license does not require you to share the source code of your
> own applications, even if they are bundled with PySide2.